# Custom condition logic not working as expected in the get record element

Tags: visual-workflow, opportunity, account

In my Get record element for the opportunity Object, my custom condition logic is not working as expected. I have designed a screen flow where the user inputs the opportunity names and the lookup account associated with the opportunity.

These are the records present in my Opportunity Object.

[image]

In the screen flow, when I give Test Opportunity 3 and Lookup Account field as HDFC, even though that record combination is available as can be seen above, it is fetching the Test Opportunity 3 and IBM record instead, that is I Believe it fetches the first record whatever available. I want only the Test Opportunity 3 and HDFC record to be chosen, if I enter that in the screen flow. Please refer my Get Record element condition given below

[image]

Eventhough Condition 1 and 2 are fulfilled, I am really not sure why it checks for the 3rd condition and chooses the wrong record. I want the flow to stop checking with first two conditions when they are true and not check for the 3rd condition. Is this any bug in the salesforce or am I going wrong anywhere? Please someone enlighten me.